# React Progress Bar with drag to increase and decrease Progress

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, progress-bar, mouseevent, react-component

I am trying to create a Progress Bar component in which I have options for Drag to increase or decrease the Progress bar width. The Drag should be done from the pointer indicating the current progress.

I have created required components and also added event listeners for mouse events like up, down, leave and move, but the width of the progress bar is not updating currently.

Here is my code,

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hopper-jfcx9

Can you please tell me where I am going wrong and will be thankful for your suggestions.

Added the code to update the width of progress bar on mouse move but it is flickering a lot.